# What Windows 'hosts' encoding is?

Tags: hosts

What the Windows 'hosts' file encoding is? Is it UTF-8? Or ASCII + system codepage? How IDN (international domain names with umlauts etc.) entries should be added and can they be added at all?

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Comment: I'm writing a GUI editor for this file. Of course, very special one. And now I'm looking for the right encoding for serialization purpose.

Comment: IDNs should probably be stored in their canonical Punycode encoded form, the rest is then just ASCII; hence the question is pretty moot.

Comment: Malware commonly wants to edit the hosts file. Not saying your app is malware, but many anti-malware apps will probably think it is.

Comment: It's an internal GUI tool for our company sysadmins. I hope they know what they're doing.

Answer (score 3):

It should be ANSI or UTF-8 without BOM. I just dealt with a server that had the hosts file encoding set to UCS-2 Little Endian, and that led to the file being ignored.

There is a wealth of information here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is
**ANSI** or **UTF-8 WITH BOM**.

(UTF-8 **without** BOM is **NOT** valid).

---

**Details**:

As far as I have tried, the encoding of the hosts file on Windows should be
ANSI or UTF-8 **with** BOM.

I know this question is many years old, but a colleague made the mistake of looking at this post and the ServerFault post, so I decided to add an answer.

### 1. Simple case only ASCII

Works.

[image: Simple case]

Without any multi-byte characters, This is equivalent to ANSI, also equivalent to UTF-8 without BOM.

### 2. ANSI (with Japanese ANSI multi-byte characters)

Works.

[image: ANSI]

note: There are Japanese characters but this is valid ANSI encoding in windows.

> In Japanese editions of Windows, this code page `cp932` is referred to as "ANSI",
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932_(Microsoft_Windows)

### 3. UTF-8 with BOM

Works.

[image: UTF8 with BOM]

note: `BOM　付き` means `with BOM`.

### 4. UTF-8 without BOM

**DOES NOT** work.

[image: UTF8 without BOM does not work]

### 5. Additional test cases

If you use emoji instead of Japanese, the result will be the same.

Use emoji and save as `UTF8 without BOM` does not work.
(However, other lines not include emoji may be worked correctly.)

[image: emoji and without BOM does not work]

Use emoji and save as `UTF8 with BOM` can resolve host correctly.
[image: emoji and with BOM WORK]

note: If you use Notepad to check it yourself, be sure to put double quotes in the file name when you save it, or Notepad will be create `hosts.txt`.

[image: do not forget double-quote when save as hosts with notepad.exe]

Appended:
(Asked in comment)
The hosts file supports inline comments.
[image]

Comment: I don't think the hosts file supports inline comments; comments have to be on their own line. So that could be affecting results.

Comment: @Triynko Microsoft shows it as an example in the hosts file. (Add that to my answer)